# OpenCV CMake configuration option: INSTALL_TO_MANGLED_PATHS

Tags: opencv, cmake, configuration

I'm kind of new to OpenCV, and I am having trouble finding information about the **INSTALL_TO_MANGLED_PATHS** option, in CMake, for OpenCV configuration. Can anyone help me understand the purpose of this option?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `INSTALL_TO_MANGLED_PATHS` configuration option can be provided in the `cmake` command line to allow OpenCV to use non-standard ("mangled") paths during installation, which is useful when you want to install two versions of OpenCV side-by-side.

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" \
  -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
  -D ENABLE_NEON=ON \
  -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=ON \
  -D INSTALL_TO_MANGLED_PATHS=ON \ 
  ...
```

CMake will append the OpenCV version to the install path names, to allow two separate versions to co-exist happily on the same machine.

See the description of this option in the OpenCV CMake [code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/8fe967430150535f8094a778e9ed6f59df940960/CMakeLists.txt#L455):

```
OCV_OPTION(INSTALL_TO_MANGLED_PATHS "Enables mangled install paths, that help with side by side installs." OFF ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I saw the description in Cmake before, but it was still not clear to me. In fact, I'm still having trouble as to why it has to be set on to off in UNIX. Also, by defect when it is off, the compiled libraries have the corresponding version on its name (in UNIX), is this why it's not necessary to set it on?

Comment: Yes, it appears that in *some* UNIX environments (e.g. excluding `ANDROID` and `APPLE_FRAMEWORK` environments), it is not applicable to have this option set to `ON`.